# How to delete dictionary values simply at a specific key 'path'?

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I want to implement a function that:

Given a dictionary and an iterable of keys,

deletes the value accessed by iterating over those keys.

Originally I had tried

```
def delete_dictionary_value(dict, keys):

    inner_value = dict
    for key in keys:
        inner_value = inner_value[key]
    del inner_value
    return dict
```

Thinking that since inner_value is assigned to dict by reference, we can mutate `dict` implcitly by mutating `inner_value`. However, it seems that assigning inner_value itself creates a new reference (`sys.getrefcount(dict[key])` is incremented by assigning `inner_value` inside the loop) - the result being that the local variable assignment is `del`ed but `dict` is returned unchanged.

Using `inner_value = None` has the same effect - presumably because this merely reassigns `inner_value`.

Other people have posted looking for answers to questions like:

- how do I ensure that my dictionary includes no values at the key `x` - which might be a question about recursion for nested dictionaries, or
- how do I iterate over values at a given key (different flavours of this question)
- how do I access the value of the key as opposed to the keyed value in a dictionary

This is none of the above - I want to remove a *specific* key,value pair in a dictionary that may be nested arbitrarily deeply - but I always know the path to the key,value pair I want to delete.

The solution I have hacked together so far is:

```
def delete_dictionary_value(dict, keys):

    base_str = f"del dict"
    property_access_str = ''.join([f"['{i}']" for i in keys])
    return exec(base_str + property_access_str)
```

Which doesn't feel right.

This also seems like pretty basic functionality - but I've not found an obvious solution. Most likely I am missing something (most likely something blindingly obvious) - please help me see.

Comment: It would be better not to overwrite the builtin function `dict`.

Comment: What do you mean by "deletes the value accessed by iterating over those keys"? Each key will be associated with a value (provided the key is in the dictionary), thus there will be multiple values associated with the keys.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `del a_dict[key]`? (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict))

Comment: how should look like a "key-path"? String?

Comment: `keys` is an iterable of keys - the aim is, given `keys=[1,2,3]` to call `del dict[1][2][3]` during a function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If error checking is not required at all, you just need to iterate to the *penultimate* key and then delete the value from there:

```
def del_by_path(d, keys):
  for k in keys[:-1]:
    d = d[k]
  return d.pop(keys[-1])

d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'Value'}}}}
del_by_path(d, 'abcd')
# 'Value'
print(d)
# {'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```

Just for fun, here's a more "functional-style" way to do the same thing:

```
from functools import reduce
def del_by_path(d, keys):
    *init, last = keys
    return reduce(dict.get, init, d).pop(last)
```

Comment: I enjoyed reading both of these suggestions. Thank you @tzaman

Comment: You're quite welcome @zapl

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a string-evaluation approach. Try to iteratively move to the last dictionary and delete the key-value pair from it. Here a possibility:

```
def delete_key(d, value_path):
    # move to most internal dictionary
    for kp in value_path[:-1]:
        if kp in dd and isinstance(d[kp], dict): 
            d = d[kp]
        else:
            e_msg = f"Key-value delete-operation failed at key '{kp}'"
            raise Exception(e_msg)

    # last entry check
    lst_kp = value_path[-1]
    if lst_kp not in d:
        e_msg = f"Key-value delete-operation failed at key '{lst_kp}'"
        raise Exception(e_msg)

    # delete key-value of most internal dictionary
    print(f'Value "{d[lst_kp]}" at position "{value_path}" deleted')
    del d[lst_kp]


d = {1: 2, 2:{3: "a"}, 4: {5: 6, 6:{8:9}}}

delete_key(d, [44, 6, 0])
#Value "9" at position "[4, 6, 8]" deleted
#{1: 2, 2: {3: 'a'}, 4: {5: 6, 6: {}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for this - the error handling is thoughtful & goes above & beyond my (caveman-level) attempts to solve this issue.